# How to send data from node/express to preview pdf in front without saving file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, next.js, puppeteer

My aim is to generate pdf contact with puppeteer with an html page that I built.

I succesfully generate this pdf in my back. But I have a problem to send data to my front. I tried many things but... One I got an arrayBuffer, once a blob, now a readableStream and I can read with my front none of theses...

Is there a way to easily send pdf and preview it in browser (in modal) ?

Here is my back :

```
const date = Date.now();
    const pathPDF = `contract-${date}.pdf`;

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(
            `http://localhost:3000/admin/reservation/${req.params.reservation}/contract`,
            {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            }
        );
        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            path: pathPDF,
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
        });

        await browser.close();

        // res.json(pdf)  <-- I tried this first, don't work

        // res.contentType('application/pdf'); 
        // res.sendFile(pathPDF); <-- Then this, not working...


        // const data = fs.readFileSync(`./${pathPDF}`);
        // res.contentType('application/pdf');
        // res.send(data); <-- I tryed this too, same...
```

Here action :

```
export const createContract = (reservation) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/reservation/contract/${reservation}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
    })
        .then((response) => {
            // return response.blob(); <-- Tried this
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Here my call in page :

```
    const generateContract = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        createContract(reservation._id).then((result) => {
            if (result.error) {
                setLoading(false);
                snackbarShowMessage(`${result.error}`);
            } else {
                setPdf(URL.createObjectURL(result)); <-- Tried this
                setPdf(result) <-- This too
                setLoading(false);
                snackbarShowMessage(`${result.message}`, 'success');
                setOpen(true);
            }
        });
    };
```

Do you have any idea where I doing wrong..?